# Info window marker android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

My doubt is the following, I have a layout with some checkbox and a text field, how do I get the selected items in checkboxes, written text and add a marker, which when clicked on it to appear in your info window?

My layout and class to add marker:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="br.selectv.CadMarkerActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txDescricao"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="333dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/descricao"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:maxLength="109"
    android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/papel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Papel"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/vidro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Vidro"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/papel"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/organico" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/plastico"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Plástico"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vidro"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txDescricao" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/metal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:text="Metal"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/organico"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Orgânico"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/metal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txTipo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Tipo"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txDescricao"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCancelar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancelar"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btOK"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/organico"
    android:onClick="cancelar" />
```

class add marker

```js
public class CadMarkerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cad_marker);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public void cancelar(View view) {
        finish();
    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        // Is the view now checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.papel:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;

            case R.id.vidro:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;

            case R.id.plastico:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;

            case R.id.metal:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;

            case R.id.organico:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;

            // TODO: Veggie sandwich
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further information.

Comment: edited post, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you will be able to get the selected items from the checkbox by checking if it's checked and for texts you should combine the code for if checkbox is checked then get the text of your checked box.

for show it in info window you should have to use AlertDialogBox and onCheckedListener on Your Check box.

i hope my idea will be work for you.